# json appending to table breaking adaptive height panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm using this: https://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/doJRBX

This is a nice responsive panel, I have a table inside this panel.

Now I have JSON appending to this table which is causing the table/panel to grow, unfortunatly it grows over the footer.

Heres my javascript:

```
$(document)
    .ready(function() {
        // Variables
        var clickedTab = $(".tabs > .active");
        var tabWrapper = $(".tab__content");
         var activeTab = tabWrapper.find(".active");
         var activeTabHeight = activeTab.outerHeight();
        // Show tab on page load
        activeTab.show();
        // Set height of wrapper on page load
         tabWrapper.height(activeTabHeight);
        $(".tabs > li")
            .on("click", function() {
                // Remove class from active tab
                $(".tabs > li")
                    .removeClass("active");
                // Add class active to clicked tab
                $(this)
                    .addClass("active");
                // Update clickedTab variable
                clickedTab = $(".tabs .active");
                // fade out active tab
                activeTab.fadeOut(250, function() {
                    // Remove active class all tabs
                    $(".tab__content > li")
                        .removeClass("active");
                    // Get index of clicked tab
                    var clickedTabIndex = clickedTab.index();
                    // Add class active to corresponding tab
                    $(".tab__content > li")
                        .eq(clickedTabIndex)
                        .addClass("active");
                    // update new active tab
                    activeTab = $(".tab__content > .active");
                    // Update variable
                    activeTabHeight = activeTab.outerHeight();
                    // Animate height of wrapper to new tab height
                    tabWrapper.stop()
                        .delay(50)
                        .animate({
                            height: activeTabHeight
                        }, 500, function() {
                            // Fade in active tab
                            activeTab.delay(50)
                                .fadeIn(250);
                        });
                });
            });
    });
$(document)
    .ready(function() {
        // Variables
        var clickedTab = $(".prices__tabs > .active");
        var tabWrapper = $(".prices__tab__content");
        var activeTab = tabWrapper.find(".active");
        var activeTabHeight = activeTab.outerHeight();
        // Show tab on page load
        activeTab.show();
        // Set height of wrapper on page load
        tabWrapper.height(activeTabHeight);
        $(".prices__tabs > li")
            .on("click", function() {
                // Remove class from active tab
                $(".prices__tabs > li")
                    .removeClass("active");
                // Add class active to clicked tab
                $(this)
                    .addClass("active");
                // Update clickedTab variable
                clickedTab = $(".prices__tabs .active");
                // fade out active tab
                activeTab.fadeOut(250, function() {
                    // Remove active class all tabs
                    $(".prices__tab__content > li")
                        .removeClass("active");
                    // Get index of clicked tab
                    var clickedTabIndex = clickedTab.index();
                    // Add class active to corresponding tab
                    $(".prices__tab__content > li")
                        .eq(clickedTabIndex)
                        .addClass("active");
                    // update new active tab
                    activeTab = $(
                        ".prices__tab__content > .active"
                    );
                    // Update variable
                    activeTabHeight = activeTab.outerHeight();
                    // Animate height of wrapper to new tab height
                    tabWrapper.stop()
                        .delay(50)
                        .animate({
                            height: activeTabHeight
                        }, 500, function() {
                            // Fade in active tab
                            activeTab.delay(50)
                                .fadeIn(250);
                        });
                });
            });
    });
```

I'm wondering if its something i can do with the activeTab in my other JS file after the prepend.

Any ideas?

Comment: `unfortunatly it grows over the footer` How? Is the footer in `position:absolute` or something? Can you create a working snippet to show us the problem a live?

Comment: I don't see any json in the code you posted?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it on coding, the footer doesn't have position absolute on it